# Binary file reading in Node converted to Python

Tags: python, node.js

I can't figure out how to handle the `readInt32LE` in my conversion of this Node script to Python.

This is a part of the Node loop:

```
while (file_offset < file_data.length)
    {
        let file = {}
        file.file_name = file_data.toString('binary', file_offset, file_offset + 13)
        file.file_name = file.file_name.substr(0, file.file_name.indexOf('.') + 4)
        file.type = file.file_name.substr(file.file_name.indexOf('.') + 1)
        file_offset += 13
        file.file_size = file_data.readInt32LE(file_offset)
```

This is my Python script:

```
while file_offset < info.st_size:
    #get filename and strip 0x00 and 0x16
    file_name = os.read(f, 13).decode('latin1')

    #strip everything but a-z, dot and digits
    file_name = re.sub('[^a-z\.\d]', '', file_name)

    #get extension without dot
    file_type = os.path.splitext(file_name)[1][-3:]

    #file_offset += 13
    file_size = os.read(f, 13).decode('latin1')
```

The file_name and file_type work so far.
If os.open reads bytes, should I convert 32 bit to byte and then read that value? I also need to take the offset in account I think? My tries so far resulted in rubbish data in `file_size`, any help appreciated.

edit:
The original script is here: https://github.com/Daivuk/Descent-Extractor/blob/master/extractor.js

It takes a 6MB file called 'descent.hog' that's an archive containing other files, and that the node script extracts. Running this part of the script results in this for example:

```
{ file_name: 'descent.txb', type: 'txb', file_size: 15415 }
{ file_name: 'briefing.txb', type: 'txb', file_size: 17308 }
{ file_name: 'credits.txb', type: 'txb', file_size: 1870 }
```

Comment: Can you provide some sample input data along with the output from the node code?

Answer (score 0):

I fixed it, this line:
`file_data.readInt32LE(file_offset)` can be replaced with:

```
file_size = os.read(f, 4); 
s = int.from_bytes(file_size, byteorder=sys.byteorder)
```

Reading 32 bits equals reading 4 bytes, and then convert it to an integer.